# Changing install location to 2 with `adb shell pm set-install-location 2' results in 'insufficient memory' errors when installing apps

Tags: adb, installation

I am using Galaxy Grand GT-19082. I used latest android sdk and unpartitioned new 32 GB SDHC Card. I used `adb shell pm set-install-location 2` and it shows that It selected 'External 2'.

After unplugging/rebooting, I tried to install some icici apps from Google Play. Once it downloaded to internal storage, it throws a 'Insufficient memory' error while trying to install. After setting 'install location' to 0, I was able to install apps at internal storage.

Even if configured as secondary storage, application was unable to install/location the secondary storage SD-card. Could you help me finding the cause?

Comment: Try to partition and format the SD-Card